# How to make all the duplicated value in each column filled by '0'

Tags: python, pandas

My Question is making all the duplicated value in each column filled by '0'.

**My data** looks like:
[image: delAction]

**Code:**

```py
df2 = df[['timestamp', 'temperature', 'humidity', 'light', 'pressure', 'speed', 'battery_voltage', 'ddp']]
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df2['timestamp'] = df2['timestamp'].map(lambda x: 
datetime.datetime.strftime(x,'%Y-%m-%d'))
df2 = df2.groupby('timestamp',as_index = False).sum()
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')
df2.sort_values(by = ['timestamp'], ascending = [True])
df2.set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
df2 = df2.resample('D').ffill().reset_index()
df2.duplicated(['temperature', 'humidity','light','pressure', 'speed', 'battery_voltage'])
```

I have used boolean method, it give me '`True`' and '`False`' back.

Comment: Since you are getting true or false use `astype(int)` at the end. It will take care of what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the *ffill()* method is the main problem. This has to be replaced with [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html). I also simplified your code a bit:

```
df2 = df[['timestamp', 'temperature', 'humidity', 'light', 'pressure', 'speed', 'battery_voltage', 'ddp']]
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).set_index('timestamp', inplace = True)
# df2 = df2.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).sum()
df2 = df2.resample('D').sum().fillna(0).reset_index()
```

The line I put in comment is not needed, but you could use it, when you want to group your data by day (and don't want to resample it)